# How to make device top panel (status bar) have the same background color as AppBar in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to make device top panel (status bar) have the same background color as AppBar in flutter? The color of the device top panel is always darker than the AppBar backgroundColor. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On iOS, this is already true.

On Android, add the following to `onCreate` in `MainActivity.java`, *after* the call to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0x00000000);
```

This will override the default status bar color of `0x40000000`, which is set in the [`onCreate`](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/51775c77a9a757074454a03e110b5c2a8574f6ed/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/app/FlutterActivityDelegate.java#L149) method of `FlutterActivityDelegate`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. It works. ^_^

Comment: any way to change the icons color? My  appbar is white

Comment: This used to work, but now my file looks like this in Kotlin. How do I get the transparent bar?

`import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

import android.os.Build
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import android.view.WindowManager
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a flutter specific solution. In the build method, you can use the flutter service package.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //top bar color
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //top bar icons
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white, //bottom bar color
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //bottom bar icons
    ));

//....
}
```