# Flutter: subtract status bar height from AppBar

Tags: flutter, statusbar, appbar

I have moved my `AppBar` downwards but now it's height is too big. I want to know how I can subtract the status bar's height from my `AppBar`'s height. Here is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Here is how you can set the `AppBar`'s height:

[Flutter: Setting the height of the AppBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089994/flutter-setting-the-height-of-the-appbar)

Here is how you can get the status bar height:

[How or where do I change the system status bar Flutter framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441187/how-or-where-do-i-change-the-system-status-bar-flutter-framework?rq=1)

```
final double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
return new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight),
      child: content
);
```

I just don't know how to put these pieces together (I am very new to Flutter so please explain the answer well)

Comment: did you try PreferredSize ?

Comment: Thanks for the statusBarHeight, I was looking for it :D

Comment: I get 0.0 for `.padding.top`

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Because you use nested Scaffords, you can try this code MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window).padding.top

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 70,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text(
              "ADVERTISE HERE!",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24),
            ),
          ),
          AppBar(title: Text("Main page")),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I battle with the fact that my object are positioned differently in the tree and then it comes out weird haha.

Answer (score 0):

now you can easily set `primary: false` and subtract the status bar's height from your AppBar's height ([Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/primary.html))

```
 AppBar(
     primary: false,
     ...
  ),
```