# How can I change status bar color in iOS?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change status bar color with `package:flutter/services.dart` package but it doesn't work. I am using Mac and iOS simulator:

- Mojave 10.14.6
- iOS 12.2 simulator / Xr
- Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.2
- Tools • Dart 2.5.0

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.red // <-- doesn't work
      )
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
... // other stuff
```

[image]

Even if I put it in the `main` function:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.red,
    )
  );
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
    .then((_) => runApp(MyApp()));
}
... // the rest code here
```

As a result I get this if I want to change `appBar` background color to white.

[image]

Haven't tested it for android yet. Is this issue related only to iOS simulator or so? How to fix it?

U.P.D.

This issue starts to drive my nuts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
appBar: AppBar(
  elevation: 0,
  brightness: Brightness.light, // this makes status bar text color black
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
)
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

`statusBarColor` can only be changed in Android and not in iOS, and probably Apple can reject your app if you try do so by some workarounds because they don't want you to have different `AppBar` and status bar color.

```
AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.red) // this changes both AppBar and status bar color in iOS
```

Apple wants you to stick to their designs which is why changing `statusBarColor` has no effect on iOS.

Comment: Nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. I copied your code but it doesn't make change, sorry.

Comment: I didn't try it on my own, let me check it out.

Comment: OK, what I found was, it is working fine in Android but not in iOS.

Comment: That's a pity news :( Somebody has put minus to this issue probably an angry flutter team developer lol

Comment: Thanks! So what should I do if I need to change status bar text color to black i.e.? Apple just cuts this possibility? I want to make white background for `appBar` but I can't change color of the text, look at [this](https://ibb.co/gRv2Tx7)

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
      backwardsCompatibility: false, "if set to false it doesn't use default app bar theme"
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor:Colors.orange,"It change the color of status bar"
      statusBarIconBrightness:  Brightness.light "It change the color of status bar icons"),
              )
              );
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try them:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white, // this one for android
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light// this one for iOS
));
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work either. Actually I need to change the color. I am surprised that it's so difficult to solve such primary and simple task for mobile dev with flutter.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers with `SystemUiOverlayStyle` weren't working in hot reload

Found this answer:

> *"... wrap the call of SystemChrome in a Future."*

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65632#issuecomment-714535817

Where only the setting `statusBarBrightness` seems to work in local iOS runtime:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1)).then(
    (value) => SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark, // bar light == text dark
        )));
```

Answer (score 0):

To everyone who is not working style setting in AppBar, try this

```
void main() {
  
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);

  runApp(const App());
}
```