# How to change status bar color in flutter in android kitkat

Tags: flutter

Hi I am Tying to change my status bar color and I am using `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));`  to change my status bar color, in oreo, pie it's working fine but not in kitkat anyone knew why?

Comment: [Try this method working in both android and ios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59949734/8555008)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying Android native method [`setStatusBarColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)) was only added in Android API Level 21. KitKat is API Level 19, and so this feature is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply do you know how i can fix this in flutter?

Comment: you can't - the underlying Android operating system does not support it.