# Can I change the bottom color on iOS (Android) with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

can we use API to change this color on iOS/Android in Flutter?

[image]

Comment: You can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441187/how-to-change-status-bar-and-app-bar-color-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can use API to change the color of the bottom safe area try with the below code. I hope your problem will be resolved.

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FutureBuilder<ModelClassName>(
      future: getColorFromAPI....,
      builder:(context,snapshot){
         final color = snapshot.data;
         return Container(
           color: color,
           child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: Scaffold(
             resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
             
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Change Bottom Bar Color',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    }
   );
  }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: this workaround works only when using AppBar, also it is not the goal, it would possibly change the status bar, this is not we want, because the goal is ONLY to change the region I pointed to.

Comment: Remove app bar from code then also work.If i am not understand your problem then please tell me in detailed i will try to help you

Comment: What does the code above do? It changes the color of the in-app bottom bar to the color of the outside-app bottom navigation bar...? Coz I wanted to do the opposite. 

Comment: The above code is used for change color of the bottom safe area of mobile.Please explain in detail what you need to change

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use with [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns/example) try this

```
import 'package:flutter_statusbarcolor_ns/flutter_statusbarcolor_ns.dart';

FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.white);
```

Without package, Recommended solution (Flutter 2.0 and above)

You have to add in "main.dart" file so it's reflect overall application.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white
));
```

Comment: Where in the app do you put this `SystemChrome` thing...?

Comment: And it seems you also need to add `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';` at the top of the screen, isn't it? Plz add this to your answer, to make it fully functional. :)