# How to make same color in AppBar in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

How to apply or use same color in flutter **AppBar**?

Check screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: here is the answer. Check this link below. Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925734/how-to-make-device-top-panel-status-bar-have-the-same-background-color-as-appb?rq=1

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I've approved your edit, but please don't reupload StackExchange images (stack.imgur.com); just apply the markup manually to existing ones and keep an image description if possible.

Comment: So, did you check the answer, find what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setSystemUIOverlayStyle`, i.e. inside `build` method

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
));
```